# Tkinter winfo_reqwidth not proper value

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a application where i will get the size of the screen and then resize GUI to take full screen accordingly.
Also, i have 3 frames inside that application. The three frames will have separate widgets. Now based on the screen size available i would like to change the layout of the widgets a bit and also the size of text and wrap length of the texts.

I understood that frame will not have proper size until it have a widget, so i am adding dummy canvas widget. But then also the width of the frames are not getting proper. Am i not doing the thing properly ? If you run the below code frame 1 and frame 2 are having same widths even though visually they are not at all same.

```
import tkinter as tk
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

class MainApplication:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
        self.height = GetSystemMetrics(1)
        self.root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(self.width, self.height))

        frame1 = tk.Frame(self.root,bg='blue')
        frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew",rowspan=2)
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=5000)
        frame1.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        frame1.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frame1,bg='blue')
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.canvas.update()
        print(frame1.winfo_reqwidth())


        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self.root,bg='red')
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.frame2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.canvas1 = tk.Canvas(self.frame2,bg='red')
        self.canvas1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.canvas1.update()
        print(self.frame2.winfo_reqwidth())

        self.frame3 = tk.Frame(self.root, bg='green')
        self.frame3.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="nsew")
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=5000)
        self.frame3.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame3.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.canvas2 = tk.Canvas(self.frame3,bg='green')
        self.canvas2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.canvas2.update()
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = MainApplication()
```

Comment: Tried `canvas.update_idletasks()` ?

Comment: I tried but its not working, also i have given the color to canvas, hence visually i can see the size being big.